# Who do i contact to resolve problems with my account?

Tags: bug

Yesterday i flagged for moderators attention, my problem being, that i was not getting notified of comments sent to me. The red notification box was not lighting up.
My flag was declined because,

Hi ,I am not getting notified of comments – Bagpipes yesterday   **declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention.**

Today i tried to up-vote an answer that i had previously down-voted. I tried to up-vote this answer because an edit had been made to it, which improved the answer.

Before i clicked on it, the answer had a total of **1** vote, and when i clicked to up-vote it,the vote should have went to **2** but it went to **3**. I clicked down again and it went back to **1**.Later i tried to up-vote again but the system would not let me. A box appeared informing me that i had already voted and my vote was locked.

I am concerned that there may be a problem in the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, flagging isn't the right way to get help, writing on Meta like this is, so thank you for coming here.

For your not getting notifications problem, as far as I can see nothing is wrong - someone else wrote a comment but didn't put a @ before your name, so the system didn't know it was directed to you, and so didn't notify you. Also, even if they put a @, if someone tries to write a comment to you on a post you have nothing to do with, you won't be notified, so as to prevent harassing/nuisance comments.

I've never heard of the second issue happening before. Maybe someone else voted at the same time, or it's some kind of caching problem? Or were you turning a downvote into an upvote, which would be a net change of +2? But unless you see it happening a lot there's no reason to think your account as problems.

Comment: Ok, thanks for  answer.